# как данные из angularjs отправить через $_POST

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, angular

не могу отправить данные из формы в php
возвращает пустой массив хотя тут все данные выводятся
пример php

```
<?php 
print_r($_POST);
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])


myApp.controller('authCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.addNewUser = function(userDetalis) {
    $scope.message = ({
      'login': userDetalis.login,
      'password': userDetalis.password
    });

    var data = $scope.message;
    var config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8;'
      }
    }
    console.log(data);
    $http.post("app/Auth.php", data, config)
      .then(
        function(response) {
          console.log(response.data);
        },
        function(response) {
          // failure callback
        }
      );
  };
});
```

```css
.carddemoBasicUsage .card-media {
  background-color: #000;
}

md-content.md-default-theme,
md-content {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  background-color: unset;
}

.inputdemoIcons {
  /*
.right-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  right: 2px;
  left: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
}
*/
}

.inputdemoIcons .inputIconDemo {
  min-height: 48px;
}

.inputdemoIcons md-input-container:not(.md-input-invalid)>md-icon.email {
  color: green;
}

.inputdemoIcons md-input-container:not(.md-input-invalid)>md-icon.name {
  color: dodgerblue;
}

.inputdemoIcons md-input-container.md-input-invalid>md-icon.email,
.inputdemoIcons md-input-container.md-input-invalid>md-icon.name {
  color: red;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .md-media-sm.card-media {
    position: relative;
    left: -65px;
    top: -10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.8/angular-material.min.css">

<body ng-cloak ng-app="MyApp">
  <div class="mx-auto w-50 pt-5">
    <div ng-controller="authCtrl" layout="column" layout-padding ng-cloak="" class="carddemoBasicUsage">
      <md-content class="md-no-momentum">
        <form name="myForm" novalidate ng-submit="addNewUser(newUser)">
          <md-input-container class="md-icon-float md-block">
            <!-- Use floating label instead of placeholder -->
            <label>Login</label>
            <md-icon><i class="material-icons">account_box</i></md-icon>
            <input ng-model="newUser.login" type="text">
          </md-input-container>

          <md-input-container md-no-float class="md-block">
            <label>Password</label>
            <md-icon><i class="material-icons">vpn_key</i></md-icon>
            <input ng-model="newUser.password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
          </md-input-container>

          <md-button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" class="md-toolbar-tools" md-colors="{background: 'deep-orange'}">
            <span class="mx-auto w-25">Log in</span>
          </md-button>
          111
          <p>{{message}}</p>
          <p>{{data}}</p>
        </form>
      </md-content>


    </div>
  </div>

  <!--
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved. 
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be foundin the LICENSE file at http://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/license.
-->


  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.8/angular-material.min.js"></script>


  <!-- Your application bootstrap  -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо $_POST попробуйте:
`$input = file_get_contents('php://input');`

Comment: спасибо помоло !!!!!!